# Difference between find_element and findElement in selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I am using `find_element` while I have seen `findElement` being used at some places in selenium. 
I am using an older version of `chromedriver`.

Are the two same or is there a difference?

I am writing codes for someone and I am just wondering if the codes would work for them if there is a difference in the version.

Here's my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Users\Nishima.Suman\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (3)\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixons_Retail')
    x= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/caption')
    print x.text
```

Comment: The syntax changes depending on the language. python/ruby: `.find_element`, Java/javascript: `.findElement`, CSharp: `.FindElement`.

Comment: Thanx!! That helped.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are actually same. There's no difference in functionality of `findElement` and `find_element`. It just depends on which programming language you using to write your script.

**JAVA:** `findElement`

**Python:** `find_element`

Make sure there's no mistake in `uppercase` and `lowercase`.

Comment: Thanx!:) That helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between them except one that `findElement()` is part of java-client and `find_element` is part of python, if we talk about functionality both are same.